# Angular i18n AOT compilation - CI deployment with nginx vs. local development with ng serve

Tags: angular, docker, internationalization, continuous-integration, angular-i18n

I am currently developing an Angular 8 app that has i18n included. I opted for the AOT approach that uses 2 separate builds/apps running in parallel. One of them is `en`, the other one `de`.

For CI, I have a pipeline that uses a Dockerfile to build the 2 different build configurations and puts them in 2 folders next to each other. In front of the 2 Angular apps I have nginx redirecting to them respective language folder depending on the URL.

Dockerfile:

```
RUN yarn ng build frontend --configuration=en
RUN yarn ng build frontend --configuration=de
```

Example:
When I access my CI deployment under `myapp.com/en`, nginx accesses the index file of the app under the `en` folder.

Nginx config:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri$args /en/index.html;
  }
  location /en/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/en/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /en/index.html;
  }
  location /de/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/de/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /de/index.html;
  }
```

This is all good and fine and it works well, but now to the actual question:

For local development I still want to be able to use a similar setup where I have two separately AOT compiled app versions, but I am looking for a way to not use nginx for my local development setup.

**Is there a way to achieve a similar i18n app structure while just using `ng serve -c <locale>` in some form?**

I know that I can have basically the same setup locally using nginx and redirecting to the correct folders, but if possible I don't want to do that so that I don't need a separate docker setup for it (I have lots of other stuff in my Dockerfile that I don't want to run locally).

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your `angular.json`:
(You probably already have the build-configuration, just adjust the `browserTarget` in the `serve-configuration` accordingly)

`angular.json`:

```
"build": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    ...
    "en": {
      "aot": true,
      "baseHref": "/en/"
      "outputPath": "dist/en/",
      "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
      "i18nFormat": "xlf",
      "i18nLocale": "en",
      ...
    }
    /* same for "de" with different params */
  }
},
"serve": {
  ...
  "configurations": {
    "en": { "port": 4201, "browserTarget": "*project-name*:build:en" },
    "de": { "port": 4202, "browserTarget": "*project-name*:build:de" }
    ...
  }
}
```

Run `ng s -c=en` or add the following to your `package.json`

```
"scripts" : {
  "serve-en": "ng serve --configuration=en",
  "serve-de": "ng serve --configuration=de",
  ...
}
```

The site will be served under http://localhost:4200/en/. Any other path than `/de` or `/en` will throw an `GET`-error. (Your config may vary)

This will build the app just like `ng serve` would, just with the build-configuration (with i18n). This may be slow on recompile, so you may want to create a separate configuration just for serving your app (without build-optimizations and such. And maybe `baseHref="/"`).

See the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-aot-compiler

---

To add to your comment:

The following will use the default-build options, the optimizations should be disabled by default. (Ports are set in the serve-config)
Build config for `"buildTarget": "project:build:en-serve"`:

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/**project-name**",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "baseHref": "/",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [...],
        "styles": [...]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "en-serve": {
          "aot": true,
          "i18nLocale": "en",
          "outputPath": "dist/en",
          "i18nFile": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
          "i18nFormat": "xlf",
          "i18nMissingTranslation": "warn"
        },
       "other configs" ...
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already have all the configuration you mentioned. But maybe it's possible to have a separate build configuration for local development that uses the JIT compiler and serves both locales at the same time. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: You could define multiple build configs (`browserTargets`) with different ports, to run them simultaneously.

JIT: According to the docs, you would have to load the locales at runtime. https://angular.io/guide/i18n#merge-with-the-jit-compiler 
Does JIT over AOT give you any advantages, you build it locally either with node or in the browser itself. So you could stick with aot, and just disable all the build optimizations.

Comment: the port has to be defined in the serve-config, next to `browserTarget` (I've added a build-config if this helps you (above))

Comment: Ok so I did some further research and found out that it actually doesn't matter at all if I use AOT or JIT. I would still have separate app bundles for every locale I want to support.
I guess I will wait until Angular 9 comes out. They seem to be changing stuff related to i18n as well. Maybe then it is possible to have one app bundle with multiple locales.